# Настройка nginx для работы с php и asp net core приложением

Tags: php, .net, nginx, asp.net-core

Есть N количество сайтов которые работают всё на одном приложении asp net core.
 Папки с этими сайтами лежат по адресу
`/var/www/test/Pages`
Название папок это домены второго уровня

```
site1.com
site2.com
.....
site99.com
```

В этих папках лежат файлы сайта а именно

```
Index.php - для главной страницы site1.com
sub1.php для домена 3 уровня sub1.site1.com
.....
sub99.php для домена 3 уровня sub99.site1.com
```

Логика приложения такая: При посещении страницы например  **sub99**.site1.com приложение проверяет есть ли файл **sub99.php** в папке `/var/www/test/Pages/site1.com/`. Если такова файла нет то приложение генерирует этот файл, сохраняет его на диск и потом отдаёт его юзеру `return Content(html, "text/html");`, если же файл есть то приложение его читает и также отдаёт юзеру.
Конфиг nginx

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
    
    server_name _; # Слушает все домены (замените "_" на "*" для старых версий Nginx)

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; # Замените на адрес, на котором работает ваше ASP.NET Core приложение
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Мне нужно что бы nginx тоже проверял есть ли файл и если его нет то отправлял запрос моему asp net core приложению а если файл есть то обрабатывал в нём php код через php-fpm.